# Tool for importing Maple worksheet into Mathematica

Tags: file-conversion

I used to use Maple (version 13 I think) and stored calculations in Maple Worksheets (*.mw files).

I do not have access to Maple anymore but can use Mathematica (version 10.1) instead.

I would like to import my old Maple Worksheets into Mathematica and save the content as notebooks.

I need a software or tool for it. Mathematica itself unfortunately does not seem to be able to do it.

If for some reason this is impossible but would be possible with access to Maple - I might be able to get access to Maple for a short while but only as last resort.